# Join two huge file without chunking with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, chunks

I have File1 with "id,name" and File2 with "id,address". I cannot load the first file (less than 2Gb): it crashes after 76k rows (with chunk concat) and only 2 columns... I cannot read_csv on the second file too because it crashes the kernel after some rows loading.

I need to join the File1 and File2 with "id" but if I cannot put files in a dataframe variable I don't know how to do...

The file is only 5Gb with 30M rows but it crashes the kernel after few seconds of loading.

How to join the file without dataframing em please ?

I have tried with chucking but it crashes.

```
chunks = []
cols = [...]
for chunk in pd.read_csv("file2.csv", chunksize=500000, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False, usecols=cols):
    chunks.append(chunk)
df = pd.concat(chunks, axis=0)
print(f.shape)
```

I need the dataframe to load to join them or join the file without loading if possible

Comment: What do you need to do with this data once it's joined?

Comment: I need to compare it to file3 (400k rows) to clean its data

Answer (score 1):

You read df2 chunk by chunk but since you append all the chunks, your resulting chunk is of the same size as your file2.

What you could do, if you are able to fully load your df1, is to join your df2 chunk by chunk like so :

```
for chunk in pd.read_csv("file2.csv", chunksize=500000, sep=',', error_bad_lines=False, low_memory=False, usecols=cols):
    df1.merge(chunk, on =['id'], how='left')
```

Comment: I have tried, I cannot even load the first file (less than 2Gb)... it crashes after 76k row (with chunk concat) and only 2 columns... WHY ??

Answer (score 0):

Chunking like that will definitely still crash your kernel, since you're still trying to fit everything into memory. You need to do something to your chunks to reduce their size.

For instance, you could read both files in chunks, join each chunk, output the matches to another file, and keep the un-matched IDs in memory. That might still crash your kernel if you get unlucky though. It depends on what your performance constraints are, and what you need to do with your data afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I didnot understand how to match the chunks. I tried to display memory but I got several different numbers... Can you please provide me some code to make me able to give you the performance of my server ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I meant in terms of how efficient you need this operation to be-- are you doing this multiple times, or with time constraints?
But if you want to know your memory, try running this command:

python -c "import os;print('Total memory: {0}\nUsed memory: {1}\nFree memory: {2}'.format(*map(int, os.popen('free -t -m').readlines()[-1].split()[1:])))"

Comment: But anyway, if you can load your first dataframe in memory just fine, then I suggest vlemaistre's approach